# Flashbots on Mumbai/polygone

Tags: json-rpc, polygon, flashbots

i'm trying to run a flashbot test on Mumbai. What is the flashbots RPC endpoint for Mumbai and Polygon network ?

Answer (score 1):

The Flashbot RPC endpoint for Mumbai is :https://rpc-mumbai.flashbots.net/

The Flashbot RPC endpoint for Polygon is: https://rpc-polygon.flashbots.net/